How can I create folders in a React Remix application for organizational purposes only
How can I create a folder within the /app/routes directory in a React Remi* application purely for organizational purposes? For example, if I have 30 files that I want to organize into different folders in the code, but without affecting the URL structure. I want the URL to remain as /test.tsx and not include the folder name, like /folder1/test.tsx. I heard there might be a way to do this by naming the folder, but I'm not sure how it works or how to implement it.
I read through the Remix framework documentation, but it seems I might be misunderstanding something. I am using v2, although I'm not entirely sure how to confirm this. I tried prefixing folder names with an underscore, like /app/routes/_folder1/test.tsx or /app/routes/__folder1/test.tsx, but it didn't have any effect. When I accessed the page (i.e. localhost:port/test.tsx), I received a 404 error both in the terminal and on the page.

If these files/etc. are not part of the routing structure then why are they in the "/app/routes" directory? Can you [edit] to provide a bit more context what issue/problem you are trying to solve for here for the solution you are asking about? In other words, is this an XY problem?

FWIW it looks like you can configure Vite to ignore route files, maybe that is what you are looking for.

According to Nested folders and nested / non-nested routes issue and the Nested folders with flat-files convention documentation section of the remix-flat-routes plugin, you need to add + at the end of the folder you want to ignore.
So try using folder1+ for the folder name

Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. What I’ve noticed is that creating a folder in the routes directory works generally, but it doesn’t work when trying to access it. For example, if you create a folder called test with a file.tsx inside it, accessing /test/file.tsx results in a 404 error for me.

@JustCool have you enabled the remix-flat-routes plugin ?

No, I haven't. But I could maybe check it out later

You could request this feature from the Remix development team, but for now what you can do is use the Vite configuration file vite.config.ts to manually define the routes associated with each route file you choose to organize in an unconventional way. It is not as easy as a special naming convention to indicate a folder should be ignored when matching the route file(s) within, but it is the recommended, catch-all alternative for those who don't always like how the Remix v2 flat routes convention works. You would not need to define the route manually for every route file, only those that are organized in a way that doesn't follow the default flat routes convention.
https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/vite-config#routes
To address some of the other suggestions:
The Vite config option to ignore route files does not apply to folders. Likewise, what you tried by starting the folder name with an underscore only works on filenames, not folders.
Even with the remix-flat-routes plugin installed and enabled, a + at the end of a folder name does not cause the folder to be ignored when matching route paths, it is just an easy way to nest your route files in folders, but have them treated like flat files, so app/routes/folder1+/test.tsx would be treated the same as app/routes/folder1.test.tsx and match with a route addressed like http://localhost:5137/folder1/test.
